# C++ Unicode Issue

Tags: c++, unicode, stdstring, widechar, wofstream

I'm having a bit of trouble with handling unicode conversions.

The following code outputs this into my text file.
HELLO??O

```
std::string test = "HELLO"; 
std::string output;
int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, 0, (LPCWSTR)test.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
char *buf = new char[len];
int len2 = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, 0, (LPCWSTR)test.c_str(), -1, buf, len, NULL, NULL);
output = buf;
std::wofstream outfile5("C:\\temp\\log11.txt");
outfile5 << test.c_str();
outfile5 << output.c_str();
outfile5.close();
```

But as you can see, output is just a unicode conversion from the test variable. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to understand why it doesn't work when you tell the compiler, "Trust me, I know it's a LPCWSTR." when it's not?

Comment: Your comment and the link helped me understand it.. do you think you can help me out with a related issue here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078661/trouble-getting-footage-path-after-effects-sdk

Comment: Read Windows Unicode section in http://utf8everywhere.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the LEN is correct after first measuring call. In general, you should not cast test.c_str() to LPCWSTR. The 'test' as is 'char'-string not 'wchar_t'-wstring. You may cast it to LPCSTR - note the 'W' missing. The WinAPI has distinction between that. You really should be using `wstring` if you want to keep widechars in it.. Yeah, after re-reading your code, the `test` should be a wstring, then you can cast it to LPCWSTR safely.

Answer (score 0):

after reading this
[Microsoft wstring reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I changed

```
std::string test = "HELLO";
```

to

```
std::wstring test = L"HELLO";
```

And the string was outputted correctly and I got

HELLOHELLO